# Android how to assign a spinner position an integer value

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

Ok, I have a spinner that is populated with strings, how can I use the array to assign a value to an integer?

for instance spinner has

1. "some value
2. "another value" etc.

When 1 is selected how can I then initialize a variable based on selection, use an if statement or switch/case?

I have included some commented code to illustrate what I'm trying to get at, in this example I have an int called 'actLevel' to be populated.

```
public class spinActMultFunction implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
        String str=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        activityMultiplier.setText(str);

        /*
         If (pos) = 1
            then actLevel = 1.2 
        else if (pos) = 2
            then actLevel = 1.6

        etc..
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Either would work but I would use a `switch`. But, what is the problem you are having?? Also, the `position` starts at 0 so `position 1` would actually be your second item

Comment: well, looks like a `switch(pos)` would solve your problem.

Comment: glad to see I was on the right tracks, I have read a lot of convulated methods of obtaining an array position. Anyway how would a switch work here? as in what am i passing as a case?

Comment: something like this?

switch (pos){
   
   
   case pos=0:
    
    actLevel = 1.2;
   break;
   case pos=1:
    
    actLevel = 1.6;
   break;
   case pos=2:
    
    actLevel= 1.8;
   
   break;
    
   
   }
im sorry i've only used a switch statement when using buttons in the past

Answer (score 0):

this worked in the end:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
                long id) {
            String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            activityMultiplier.setText(str);

            switch(pos){

            case 0:
                actLevel = 1.2;
                break;

            case 1:
                actLevel = 1.3;
                break;

            case 2:
                actLevel = 1.5;
                break;

            case 3:
                actLevel = 1.7;
                break;
            case 4:
                actLevel = 1.9;
                break;

            }

        }
```